# Curl + reading from file

Tags: bash, curl, debian

I have a server where I'm trying to read information using curl. I would like my bash script to read the account numbers written in a file and then query the server using curl.

```
file="cdr.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
echo ""
echo $line
curl http://server.mydomain.net/api/v1/subscribers?cli=$line -u 'auth:auth'
echo ""
done <"$file"
```

This works -

```
curl http://server.mydomain.net/api/v1/subscribers?cli=0800 -u 'auth:auth
```

With the next command, I have been trying to get the curl command to run using the string value read from the file -

```
curl http://server.mydomain.net/api/v1/subscribers?cli=$line -u 'auth:auth
```

output -

```
0800
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

As you can see it's not happy with the syntax.

I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate some pointers

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: Have you tried to echo the curl command, with the $line variable, to see what URL is calling? Anyway I would double quote the entire URL

Comment: try this `done < <(sed $'s/\r$//' "$file")` instead of `done < "$file"`

Comment: Thanks, @franzisk i had not thought of using echo.

Comment: @Fravadona thank you very much this solved the issue. Could you explain what that line is doing?

Comment: It's a very common issue: When processing a Windows text file with UNIX tools you end up with an unwanted `CARRIAGE RETURN` character at the end of the string. UNIX splits the line at '\n' while Windows uses `\r\n`